# Item selected to send to a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm beginning in JQuery, and I'd like to know if there is a way to send a selected item from a selectlist to a JQuery function.

So, here is the fiddle I've used :
http://jsfiddle.net/YCPM7/7/

I'd like to know if there is a way to replace the 'option:select' that I've set inside the call of the function.

Here is a part of the code that's on the fiddle :

```
 <select id="StateSelection1" name="StateSelection">
                <option value="1">state 1</option>
                <option value="2">state 2</option>
                <option value="3">state 3</option>
                <option value="4">state 4</option>
                <option value="5">state 5</option>
            </select>
        </td><td>
            <input type="button" value="envoi" class="bouton" name="test" onclick="switchDiv(1, 'option:select')"/>
```

the '1' that you can see inside "switchDiv(1, 'option:select')" is not really important. That's an id that will be generated by razor (vb.net).

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you using inline `onclick` event handlers?

Comment: If you're learning jQuery anyway, you should learn about attaching event handlers with it instead of "onclick" attributes. *edit* ha ha

Comment: ain't there really no way to get the option selected inside a onclick event? (yeah I admit that doing that way is looking for the easy way (like almost every programmer I assume^^))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I choose to do this with a onClick method, which seemed to be a lot easier :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function switchDiv(idCont) {
          value = $('#DivSelection' + idCont + ' option:selected').val();  
        alert("contactid = " + idCont + " DivSelected = " + value);
        $("#" + idCont + "1").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "2").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "3").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "4").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "5").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "6").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "7").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "8").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + "9").hide();
        $("#" + idCont + value).show();
    };

</script> 

     <input id=@item.idContact type="button" value="Envoyer" class="bouton" onclick="switchDiv(@item.idContact)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy do. First of all, put an ID to the button. Let's call it btnTest.

And now, to the jQuery part, use this :

```
$("#btnTest").click( function() {
    alert($("#StateSelection1 option:selected").text());
});
```

This will get the Text of the select, to get the index use val() instead of text()

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how many buttons I'll have. That means that I'll have to generate the script from razor... And that's something I don't really like to do.

Comment: You mean that you'll generate the javascript via server side, you can use vb.net to generate it, you can use ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", YOUR SCRIPT HERE) and put it on the event OnInit.

Comment: You can use an HtmlHelper to make sure the generated script goes to the correct part of your page.  - I use a variant of this method: http://frugalcoder.us/post/2009/06/29/Handling-Scripts-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: Hm, I got confused, I know that on vb.net you could do that. But to get the selector value on jquery, you can use that code.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried not to edit the HTML you've shown in your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCPM7/7/) too much, only adding the `.js-target, .js-1` and `.js-2` classes to help explain what's being done.

The below bit of jQuery should hide all of the divs to begin with, and then when clicking on one of the buttons, hide them all again and just display the div whose option was selected.

```
$(".js-target").hide();

$(".bouton").on("click", function() {
    $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("js-1")) {
        number = "1";
    } else if ($this.hasClass("js-2")) {
        number = "2";
    }

    target = $('#StateSelection' + number + ' option:selected').val();

    $(".js-target").hide();

    $("#" + number + "/" + target).show();
});​
```

The [fiddle can be viewed here](http://jsfiddle.net/YCPM7/11/).

Comment: ain't there any problem with $("#" + number + "/" + target).show();
, because there is never anything that's shown. However, if I put a "alert(number + target);" just before the $("#" + number + "/" + target).show();, the alert is well displayed.

Comment: problem found : "/" is not an authorized caracter inside the ID

Answer (score 0):

once u get the value to select u can use

```
$("#btnTest").click( function() {
    $("#StateSelection1").val(YOUR_VALUE);
    }
```

Comment: I don't get what you want me to do with this :-(. I'm only beginning and I really don't see what the "YOUR_VALUE" has to do here.